# ASP.NET MVC Query with both CASE statement and SUM function

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-core

I've found some solutions for this problem, but i don't know why it is not working...
I am using ASP.NET MVC

My database has 2 tables: `HealthRegister` & `Member`.

Each HealthRegister has one Member and each Member has many Member.

```cs
public class HealthRegistration
    {
        [Key]
        public int HealthRegistrationID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Member")]
        public string MemberRegistrationNumber { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Data e hora do registro")]
        public DateTime RegisterDateTime { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Está de sentindo bem?")]
        public bool HowRUFeeling { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Falta de ar")]
        public bool FaltaDeAr { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Cansaço")]
        public bool Cansaco { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Febre")]
        public bool Febre { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Calafrios")]
        public bool Calafrios { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Tosse")]
        public bool Tosse { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Dor de garganta")]
        public bool DorDeGarganta { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Dor de cabeça")]
        public bool DorDeCabeca { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Dor no peito")]
        public bool DorNoPeito { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Perda de olfato")]
        public bool PerdaDeOlfato { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Perda de paladar")]
        public bool PerdaPaladar { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Diarreia")]
        public bool Diarreia { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Coriza")]
        public bool Coriza { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Espirros")]
        public bool Espirros { get; set; }
        public virtual Member Member { get; set; }
    }

public class Member
    {
        public enum Sectors
        {
            Administrador,
            Aluno,
            Professor,
            Funcionario            
        }

        [Key]
        [Display(Name = "Número de matrícula")]
        public string MemberRegistrationNumber { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Nome")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Setor")]
        public Sectors Sector { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Senha")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "Date")]
        [Display(Name = "Data de nascimento")]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Cidade")]
        public string City { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Estado")]
        public string State { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Administrador")]
        public bool Admin { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Registros de saúde")]
        public virtual ICollection<HealthRegistration> HealthRegistrations { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to make the following SQL query in ASP.NET MVC:

```sql
SELECT
    CONVERT(DATE, RegisterDateTime),
    SUM(CASE WHEN Sector = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    SUM(CASE WHEN Sector = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    SUM(CASE WHEN Sector = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    SUM(CASE WHEN Sector = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM
    [dbo].[HealthRegistration]
    INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[Member]
    ON [dbo].[Member].MemberRegistrationNumber = [dbo].[HealthRegistration].MemberRegistrationNumber
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, RegisterDateTime);
```

I have tried this solution with an error message:

```cs
var registerBySectorByDate = await _context.HealthRegistration
                .Include(m => m.Member)
                .Where(m => DateTime.Compare(m.RegisterDateTime, fromDate) >= 0 && DateTime.Compare(m.RegisterDateTime, toDate) <= 0)
                .GroupBy(m => m.RegisterDateTime.Date)
                .Select(m => new
                {
                    Key = m.Key,
                    x = m.Sum(n => n.Member.Sector == Member.Sectors.Administrador ? 1 : 0)
}).ToListAsync();
```

Error message:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'GroupByShaperExpression:
      KeySelector: CONVERT(date, h.RegisterDateTime),
      ElementSelector:EntityShaperExpression:
          EntityType: HealthRegistration
          ValueBufferExpression:
              ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
          IsNullable: False

          .Sum(n => (int)n.Member.Sector == 0 ? 1 : 0)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
         at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
         at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateInternal(Expression expression)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.Translate(Expression expression)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.VisitNew(NewExpression newExpression)
         at System.Linq.Expressions.NewExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
         at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Translate(SelectExpression selectExpression, Expression expression)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateSelect(ShapedQueryExpression source, LambdaExpression selector)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
         at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
         at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1.<ExecuteAsync>b__0()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredCancelableAsyncEnumerable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at ManagerCovid19.Controllers.HealthController.Filter(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate) in C:\Users\fekel\source\repos\ManagerCovid19\ManagerCovid19\Controllers\HealthController.cs:line 59
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

What am i doing wrong??

Comment: This is more of an EntityFrameworkCore question, it doesn't appear to be specific to the fact you're using ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is related to the change in EF Core 3.x and above -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client

It cant translate the x = m.Sum(n => n.Member.Sector == Member.Sectors.Administrador ? 1 : 0) expression into SQL so its throwing an exception(as its expected too)

The documentation says to call AsEnumberable() or ToList() first, so that it can be called on the client side.

Comment: Thanks... It worked